# Hitting a REST-based Service With AngularJS Resource

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS app. In this app, I'm trying to ping a REST API. This API returns a list of orders. 
I need to be able to handle the scenario where I successfully GET the orders. I also need to handle the 
scenario where the request to GET the orders fails. In an attempt to do this, I'm using the ngResource
module. My controller looks like the following:

**myController.js**

```
myApp.controller('myController',
    function myController($scope, myService) {
        myService.getOrders(function(data) {
            $scope.orders = data;
        });
    }
);
```

The definition of myService is stored in **myService.js**. That file looks like this:

```
app.factory("myyService", function($resource, $log) {
   return {
       getOrders: function(onSuccess) {
           var orders = $resource("http://localhost:1000/orders", { fetch:{method:'JSON'} });
           orders.fetch(function (response) {
               console.log(response);
                onSuccess(response.data);
           });
       }
   };
});
```

When I run this code, I get a runtime error. The error says:

```
TypeError: Object function g(b){z(b||{},this)} has no method 'fetch'
```

Maybe there has to be something I don't understand. In my mind, I see fetch defined.

The other question I have is how do I set this up to handle failed requests? Like a 404 or 502?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the curly braces after the URL parameter...

Change: `http://localhost:1000/orders", { fetch :`

To: `http://localhost:1000/orders", {}, { fetch :`

```
app.factory("myyService", function($resource, $log) {
   return {
       getOrders: function(onSuccess) {
           var orders = $resource("http://localhost:1000/orders", {}, { fetch : {method:'JSON'} });
           orders.fetch(function (response) {
               console.log(response);
                onSuccess(response.data);
           });
       }
   };
});
```

**[EDIT]**

To handle errors from the server side, you need to set the second function in the resource call.

Example :

```
orders.fetch(function success() {...}, 
             function error() {... this will execute in a http error, 400 or 500}
);
```

Comment: how do you handle errors though? For instance, what if the web service returns a 404 or 502?